# Range in range sum with point update

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, segment-tree

We are given an array A with N elements and also N ranges, each of the form [L, R].  Call the *value* of a range the sum of all the elements in A from index L to index R, inclusive.

Example : Let Array A = [2 5 7 9 8] and a range given is [2,4] then value of this range is 5+7+9=21

Now we are given Q queries each query of one of the 2 types:

```
1. 0 X Y : It means change Xth element of array to Y.
2. 1 A B : It means we need to report the sum of values of ranges from A to B.
```

**Example :** Let array A = [2 3 7 8 6 5] and let we have 3 ranges :

```
R1: [1,3] Then value corresponding to this range is 2+3+7=12
R2: [4,5] Then value corresponding to this range is 8+6=14
R3: [3,6] Then value corresponding to this range is 7+8+6+5=26
```

Now let we have 3 queries:

```
Q1: 1 1 2
Then here answer is value of Range1 + value of Range2 = 12+14=26 

Q2: 0 2 5
It means Change 2nd element to 5 from 3.It will change the result of Range 1.
Now value of Range1 becomes 2+5+7=14

Q3: 1 1 2
Then here answer is value of Range1 + value of Range2 = 14+14=28
```

How to do it if we have 10^5 Queries and N is also upto 10^5. How to report to Queries2 in an efficient way ?

**My Approach :** The first query can be handled easily. I can build a segment tree from the array. I can use it to calculate the sum of an interval in the first array (an element in the second array). But how can i handle the second query in O(log n)? In the worst case, the element I update will be in all the intervals in the second array.

I need a O(Qlog N) or O(Q(logN)^2) solution.

Obviously we cant have a O(N) for each query.So please help to get efficient way

My Current Code :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long long  arr[100002],i,n,Li[100002],Ri[100002],q,j;
long long  queries[100002][2],query_val[100002],F[100002],temp;
long long   ans[100002];
int main()
{
scanf("%lld",&n);
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    scanf("%lld",&arr[i]);
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    scanf("%lld%lld",&Li[i],&Ri[i]);
}
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    F[n] = 0;
    ans[i] = 0;
}
scanf("%lld",&q);
for(i=1;i<=q;i++)
{
    scanf("%lld",&query_val[i]);
    scanf("%lld%lld",&queries[i][0],&queries[i][1]);
}
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(j=Li[i];j<=Ri[i];j++)
    {
        F[i] = F[i] + arr[j];
    }
}
long long  diff;
long long  ans_count = 0,k=1;
for(i=1;i<=q;i++)
{
    if(query_val[i] == 1)
    {
        temp = arr[queries[i][0]];
        arr[queries[i][0]] = queries[i][1];
        diff =  arr[queries[i][0]] - temp;
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if(queries[i][0]>=Li[j] && queries[i][0]<=Ri[j])
                F[j] = F[j] + diff;
            ++k;
        }

    }
    else if(query_val[i] == 2)
    {
        ++ans_count;
        for(j=queries[i][0];j<=queries[i][1];j++)
            ans[ans_count] = ans[ans_count] + F[j];

    }
}
for(i=1;i<=ans_count;i++)
{
    printf("%lld\n",ans[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Though the code is correct but for larger test cases it take huge time.Please help

Comment: @j_random_hacker How ?Please help by providing some explanation

Comment: I really can't explain it better than the original paper by Peter Fenwick, which you can get to from the Wikipedia page, which is the first Google result for "Fenwick tree".

Comment: It sounds like you already have the right approach... each element should only appear in at most `log N` intervals of the segment tree.

Comment: @arghbleargh Can you please explain how you get it ?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I know Fenwick trees but how are you implementing them here ?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I think you didnt get the question correctly

Comment: You're right, and I'm sorry for my angry comment, which I've now removed.  Your first sentence doesn't make grammatical sense, so I assumed this was a similar-sounding problem that comes up often, but the rest of your question makes it clear.  I don't know how to tackle this problem, sorry.

Comment: @j_random_hacker No problem.I think it can be done by square root decomposition.But not sure about it

Comment: You have correctly identified segment tree as the data structure to use, but what you've implemented isn't actually a segment tree (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). I suggest you store sums of  all ranges of the form [k * 2^m, (k + 1) * 2^m].

Comment: @arghbleargh Can you please explain,am not getting you .My though of segment tree is not complete acc to me

Comment: Reading your question again I realized it's a different problem from what I thought. Are you sure there are no additional constraints?

Comment: @arghbleargh Yeah their are no additional constraints

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
void updateSegementLazyTree(ll *tree , ll *lazy , ll low, ll high,ll startR ,ll endR ,ll updateValue ,ll treeNode)
{

    //before using current node we need to check weather currentnode has any painding updation or not
    if (lazy[treeNode]!=0)
    {
        //update painding updation
        tree[treeNode]  +=  (high-low+1)*lazy[treeNode];
        //transfer update record to child of current node if child possible
        if (low!=high)
        {
            //that's means child possible
            lazy[treeNode*2]    += lazy[treeNode];  //append update to left child
            lazy[treeNode*2+1]  += lazy[treeNode];  //append update to right child
        }
        lazy[treeNode]=0;//remove lazyness of current node
    }
    //if our current interval [low,high] is completely outside of the given Interval[startR,endR]
    if (startR >high || endR <low || low>high)
    {   
        //then we have to ignore those path of tree
        return;
    }
    //if our current interval is completely inside of given interval
    if (low >=startR && high <=endR)
    {
        //first need to update the current node with their painding updation
        tree[treeNode]  += (high-low+1)*updateValue;
        if (low!=high)
        {
            //that's means we are at the non-leaf node
            lazy[treeNode*2] +=updateValue; //so append lazyness to their left child
            lazy[treeNode*2+1] +=updateValue;//append lazyness to their right child
        }
        return;
    }
    //partially inside and outside then we have to traverse all sub tree i.e. right subtree and left subtree also
    ll mid=(low+high)/2;
    updateSegementLazyTree(tree ,  lazy ,  low,  mid, startR , endR , updateValue , treeNode*2);
    updateSegementLazyTree(tree ,  lazy ,  mid+1,  high, startR , endR , updateValue , treeNode*2+1);

    //while poping the function from stack ,we are going to save what i have done....Ok!!!!
    //update tree node:-
    tree[treeNode]  = tree[treeNode*2] + tree[treeNode*2+1];    //left sum+rightsum(after updation)
}
ll getAnswer(ll *tree ,ll * lazy , ll low, ll high ,ll startR,ll endR , ll treeNode)
{
    //base case
    if (low>high)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    //completely outside
    if (low >endR || high <startR)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    //before using current node we need to check weather currentnode has any painding updation or not
    if (lazy[treeNode]!=0)
        {
            //i.e. if we would have added x value from low to high then total changes for root node will be (high-low+1)*x
            tree[treeNode]  += (high-low+1)*lazy[treeNode];
            if (low!=high)
            {
                //if we are at non-leaf node
                lazy[treeNode*2] += lazy[treeNode]; //append updateion process to left tree
                lazy[treeNode*2+1] += lazy[treeNode];//append updation process to right tree
            }
            lazy[treeNode]=0;
        }
    //if our current interval is completely inside of given interval
    if (low >=startR && high <=endR)
    {
        return tree[treeNode];
    }
    //if our current interval is cpartially inside and partially out side of given interval then we need to travers both side left and right too
    ll mid=(low+high)/2;
    if(startR>mid)
    {
        //that's means our start is away from mid so we need to treverse in right subtree
        return getAnswer( tree ,  lazy ,  mid+1, high, startR, endR ,  treeNode*2+1);
    }else if(endR <= mid){
        //that's means our end is so far to mid or equal so need to travers in left subtree
        return getAnswer( tree ,  lazy ,  low, mid, startR, endR ,  treeNode*2);
    }
    ll left=getAnswer( tree ,  lazy ,  low, mid, startR, endR ,  treeNode*2);   //traverse right
    ll right=getAnswer( tree ,  lazy ,  mid+1, high, startR, endR ,  treeNode*2+1); //and left
    return (left+right);//for any node total sum=(leftTreeSum+rightTreeSum)
}
int main()
{
    int nTestCase;
    cin>>nTestCase;
    while(nTestCase--)
    {
        ll n,nQuery;
        cin>>n>>nQuery;
        ll *tree=new ll[3*n]();
        ll *lazy=new ll[3*n]();
        while(nQuery--)
        {
            int choice;
            cin>>choice;
            if (choice==0)
            {
                ll startR,endR,updateValue;
                cin>>startR>>endR>>updateValue;
                //0:- start index , n-1 end index ,1 treeIndex tree is our segment tree and lazy is our lazy segment tree
                updateSegementLazyTree(tree , lazy , 0, n-1, startR-1 , endR-1 , updateValue , 1);
            // for (int i = 0; i < 3*n; ++i)
            //  {
            //      cout<<i<<"\t"<<tree[i]<<"\t"<<lazy[i]<<endl;
            //  }
            }else{
                ll startR,endR;
                cin>>startR>>endR;
                ll answer=getAnswer(tree , lazy , 0, n-1 , startR-1 , endR-1 , 1);
                cout<<answer<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`updateSegementLazyTree()` take two arrays of size `4*n` because the total number of possible nodes with the length of  `log(n)` will be `2*2^log(n)` that at most is `4*n`. Then we also need `interval[startR,endr]` and `updateValue` that we maintain through recrusion. `Tree[treeNode]` represents the sum of all elements from left and right.

Sample input looks like:

```
1
8 6
0 2 4 26
0 4 8 80
0 4 5 20
1 8 8 
0 5 7 14
1 4 8
```

So for the first query we have to update `2-4` with +26. Instead of updating all elements between 2-4 we just store it in our lazy tree and whenever we access any node from the tree we first check weather this node has any pending update. If there are no pending updates, then complete and shift this to their child.

```
q1:- 0 2 4 26
tree[0,78,78,0,26,52,0,0,0,26]
```

try to make tree index; for left `tree(2*i+1)` and `right(2*i+1)`
1-st index is at least 78 i.e. top of tree so from `[0,n-1]` current max is 78.

`tree[treeNode] +=  (high-low+1)*lazy[treeNode];`

If we add `x` from low index to high then in overall sub array `i` have added  `(high-low+1)*x ; -1` because of indexing from `0`.

Then, before accessing any node from tree we lazy check weather that node has any pending update. `if (lazy[treeNode]!=0)` If it has, then update and transfer lazy to their child. Keep doing that for left subtree and right subtree as well.

Then we reach `getAnswer()` within `range[startR,endR]`
As I mentioned before, we first check for pending updates for each affected node. If true then it completes that update and call recursively left and right subtree according to the interval.

At the end we have the sum of `leftSubtree` and sum of `rightsubtree` of root node, add them and return them.

**Time Complexity**

In update, `getAnswer()`, in worst case will have to traverse the entire tree i.e. height of tree `O(2*Log N)`. `2*log n` because it is the worst case we have to travel in left and right subtree e.g. for interval `[0-n-1]`.

For `k` query, overall time complexity would be `O(K*log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Segment Tree. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/

```
#include <cstdio>

const int MAX_N = 1000003;

int tree[(1 << 21) + 3], a[MAX_N], N, M;
int x, y;

int query(int n, int l, int r) {
    if(l > y || r < x) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(l >= x && r <= y) {
        return tree[n];
    }
    int q = query(2*n, l, (l + r)/2);
    int p = query(2*n + 1, (l + r)/2 + 1, r);
    return p + q;
}

void init(int n, int l, int r) {
    if(l == r) {
        tree[n] = a[l];
        return;
    }
    init(2*n, l, (l + r)/2);
    init(2*n + 1, (l + r)/2 + 1, r);
    tree[n] = tree[2*n] + tree[2*n + 1];
}

void update(int n, int l, int r) {
    if(l > y || r < x)
        return;
    if(l == r && x == r) {
        tree[n] = y;
        return;
    }
    else if(l == r) {
        return;
    }
    update(2*n, l, (l + r)/2);
    update(2*n + 1, (l + r)/2 + 1, r);
    tree[n] = tree[2*n] + tree[2*n + 1];
}
int main() {
    scanf("%d%d", &N, &M);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    init(1, 0, N - 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        int c;
        scanf("%d%d%d", &c, &x, &y);
        if(!c) {
            a[x] = y;
            update(1, 0, N - 1);
        } else {
            printf("%d\n", query(1, 0, N - 1));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basic idea is to extend your array of elements into a binary tree. Every node of that tree holds information about sum of the elements of its children. And you can easily know which range is some node covering by applying this trick:

Root is holding information of range `[1,N]`.
Left child of the root is holding information about range `[1, int(N/2)]`.
Right child of the root is holding information about range `[int(N/2)+1, N]`.

In general if node 'A' is holding information about range `[l, r]`. Then left child
holds information about range `[l, int((l+r)/2)]` and right child is holding information
about range `[int((l+r)/2)+1, r]`.

There is also a good trick to represent binary tree in array.
Lets say that you hold your tree in array 'tree' (as I am doing I my code). Then root of that
tree will be in `tree[1]`. Left child of the root is going to be `tree[2]` and right child of tree
root is going to be `tree[3]`.

In general if you are on the node `n` then its left child is `2*n` and right child is `2*n + 1`.

That is why I am calling my `query` and `update` function with (1, 0, N - 1). I start with the root node `1`. And range that I am covering with that node i [0, N-1]. And I am always trying to find first node what fits in the range that I need to calculate the sum of.

That's a start. Try googling more about Segment Trees. When you start exploring you will see that there is a couple of ways you can represent your tree.

Good luck. :)